# Request routes for emergency vehicles using HERE Android SDK Premium Edition

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

Is there a way to get routes for EMERGENCY_VEHICLES directly using the Android SDK Premium Edition? Ive read these links and still dont understand how to do it.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/vehicle-types-and-measures.html

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.17/dev_guide/topics/fleet-connectivity.html

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.16/dev_guide/topics/fleet-telematics-custom-route.html

I thought I could request emergency vehicle routes using the FTCRRouter with an FTCRRouteOptions but I cant seem to find a method to specify emergency vehicle type, only TransportMode, and that only allows me to specify Truck, like the regular RouteOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/vehicle-types-and-measures.html

In case to utilize the REST API of Fleet Telematics API you can: calculate the route for emergency vehicle type also you can set comma separated list of types:

> A comma separated list of vehicle types enables all permissions that
> each of these vehicle types have.

But unfortunately, it is not possible calculate a route for emergency vehicle type using the FTCR route calculation because some of type of vehicles have been never implemented for FTCR route calculation, additionally mSDK 3.x is **in maintenance mode** that means it will be never developed new features for mSDK 3.x.

In mSDK 4.x - regarding this https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.7.6.0/dev_guide/topics/routing.html#get-routes unfortunately doesn't exist route options for emergency type, maybe it will be implemented later but road map is unknown.

Comment: I am not using the Navigate Edition, I use the lastest version of Premium Edition (3.18)